# What is the limit of the sum as `t` approaches infinity?

Tags: performance-tuning, code-review, code-request

I am unable to find the limit of the following sum as `t` appraoches infinity

```
Clear["Global`*"]
S[t_] := S[
   t] = (1/(t - 1)) Sum[
    Sum[Abs[(t)/((t - 1) n (n + 1)) - 1/(t - 1)], {n, 1, j}], {j, 1, 
     t - 1}]
```

As `t` grows larger the computation time of the sum slows down.

How do we compute the limit?

**Edit:** According to the comments I tried `RealAbs` and computed the limit as `t->Infinity`

```
Clear["Global`*"]
S[t_] := S[
   t] = (1/(t - 1)) Sum[
    Sum[RealAbs[(t)/((t - 1) n (n + 1)) - 1/(t - 1)], {n, 1, j}], {j, 
     1, t - 1}]
N[Limit[S[t], {t -> Infinity, Assumptions -> Element[t, Reals]}]]
```

However, the computation time takes forever to compute.

Comment: If `t` is real, try adding it as an assumption and using `RealAbs` instead of `Abs`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I tried using `RealAbs` and `Limits` but my sums still takes a long time to compute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can make an asymptotic approximation by hand and take its limit:

```
sum = (1/(t - 1)) Sum[    (* takes ~80 sec *)
    RealAbs[(t)/((t - 1) n (n + 1)) - 1/(t - 1)], {j, 1, t - 1}, {n, 
     1, j}, Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals];

asymp = FullSimplify[sum /. Ceiling | Floor -> Identity, t > 100] /. 
    f : _PolyGamma | _HarmonicNumber :> 
     With[{res = Normal@Series[f, {t, Infinity, 3}]}, res /; True] // 
   Simplify;

Limit[asymp, t -> Infinity]
(* 3/2 *)
```

Numerical evidence for the validity of the approximation. I'll let someone else prove it rigorously.

```
TableForm[
 Table[Style[sum - asymp, PrintPrecision -> 16] // AbsoluteTiming, {t,
    10.`32^Range@10}],
 TableHeadings -> {Automatic, {"Timing", "Sum"}}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Continuation of the fine answer of @MichaelE2

```
sum = (1/(t - 1)) Sum[
Abs[(t)/((t - 1) n (n + 1)) - 1/(t - 1)], {j, 1, t - 1}, {n, 1, 
 j}, Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals] // Simplify[#, t > 2] &

(*   (-4 (-1 + t) Floor[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 t])]^2 + 
2 Floor[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 t])]^3 + 
t (1 - 2 EulerGamma + t - 
  2 PolyGamma[0, 2 + Floor[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 t])]]) + 
Floor[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 t])] (2 - 3 t - 2 EulerGamma t + 
  3 t^2 - 2 t PolyGamma[0, 
    2 + Floor[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 t])]]))/(2 (-1 + t)^2 (1 + 
 Floor[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 t])]))   *)
```

The argument of all Floor is the same and it goes to infinity as t goes to infinity. It is sufficient to regard only cases where this is an integer and therefore Floor->Identity.

```
solt = First@Solve[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 t]) == k, t, Integers] // 
   Simplify[#, {t \[Element] Integers, k \[Element] Integers, k > 2}] &

(*   {t -> k (1 + k)}   *)

sum2 = sum /. solt // Simplify[#, k \[Element] Integers && k > 2] &

(*   (k (1 + k) (3 - 2 EulerGamma - 3 k + 3 k^2 - 
     2 PolyGamma[0, 2 + k]))/(2 (-1 + k + k^2)^2)   *)

Limit[sum2, k -> \[Infinity]]

(*   3/2   *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do both divisions by (t-1) belong in the expression? If not, it must diverge.  To see that, lay out the terms for any `t` as a lower triangular matrix.  E.g.,

```
With[{t = 5}, PadRight@
 Table[Abs[t/(n (n + 1)) - 1]/(t - 1), {j, 1, t - 1}, {n, 1, j}]] // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{3}{8} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{3}{8} & \frac{1}{24} & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{3}{8} & \frac{1}{24} & \frac{7}{48} & 0 \\
 \frac{3}{8} & \frac{1}{24} & \frac{7}{48} & \frac{3}{16} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

All the entries must be positive. In any column, all the entries are the same. Now look at the first column.  It's entries are all `(t/2 - 1)/(t-1)`, which has a limit of (1/2). If the double-deflation by $(t-1)$ was intentional, then after weighting this column has a limiting sum of $1/2$, which puts a floor under the total.

Comment: Numerically, I'm getting a limit of 3/2 (up to $t=10^{12}$).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ah, I failed to deflate by (t-1).